# Ignore characters in between quote

Tags: java

I have several strings like this from a file, my code tells it to split each line by a comma and if a line is author, output it, if it is title output it, e.t.c. As labelled, no 2 prints out the output but no 1 prints out only title and journal, i basically think its because of the characters in between, here is my code that splits, how do i tell it to ignore the characters in between or replace them.

```
1. @Article{Balogh:2015:OBW,
  author =       "J{\'a}nos Balogh and J{\'o}zsef B{\'e}k{\'e}si and
                 Gy{\"o}rgy D{\'o}sa and Leah Epstein and Hans Kellerer
                 and Asaf Levin and Zsolt Tuza",
  title =        "Offline black and white bin packing",
  journal =      {Theor. Comput. Sci.}
}

2.@Article{DAngelo:2015:MSP,
  author =       "Gianlorenzo D'Angelo and Daniele Diodati and Alfredo
                 Navarra and Cristina M. Pinotti",
  title =        "The minimum $k$-storage problem on directed graphs",
  journal =      {Theor. Comput. Sci.}
}
```

Code that splits.

```
printArray = InArray[i].trim().split( ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))" ,-1);
```

i have tried this

```
printArray = InArray[i].trim().split(",");
```

this

```
//InArray[i]=InArray[i].replaceAll("[{}]","").replaceAll("[\\\"]", "");
         printArray = InArray[i].trim().split( ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))" ,-1);
```

but i keep getting `index out of bound exception`

Comment: Post [add to your question by using [edit]] your exact exception and the part of the code it complains about.

Comment: what is `InArray` and what is `i`? I guess the out of bounds is coming from there

Comment: My guess is that the OOB comes when accessing `printArray` which contains less substrings than expected.

Comment: Unless you're doing this as an exercise in parsing, there exist several [BibTeX parsers](https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex).

Comment: Instead of splitting the string you could also use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with capturing groups to extract the data you want. E.g. with a regex like `"^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(.+),$"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically did this to fix this.

```
printArray = InArray[i].replaceAll("\\\\\"", "").trim().split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))
```